# How to tackle Syntax Error in ChartJS Doughnut options?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying (hard) to customize a ChartJS donought as needed. Whenever I insert the `cutoutPercentage: 70` option, I receive syntax errors from JSlint.

No matter which position I insert the option, it won't work. If I only insert `cutoutPercentage: 70` without `legend and tooltip options` it works just fine... but not in combination.

**Working:**

```
      options:{
         legend: {
            display: false
         },
         tooltips: {
            enabled: true
         }
       }
```

**working as well**:

```
     options: {
       cutoutPercentage: 70
              }
```

**Not working:**

```
      options:{
         legend: {
            display: false
         },
         tooltips: {
            enabled: true
         }
         cutoutPercentage: 70              
       }
```

Comment: It is working fine for me. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/u58rot7p/). Can you share a fiddle with your code. Also you don't have a ',' after the tooltip option.  `tooltips: {enabled: true } cutoutPercentage: 70  `

Comment: It was the missing comma that made my code go nuts.... Thanks mate, coding can be so tough when it comes to the details... ;p